# How do I "NOT require" a passcode in Apple Configurator

Tags: password, apple-configurator

Since apparently I can't set a passcode automatically with configurator I'd like to not have a passcode required (I'm okay with the user setting one themselves as long as it'll get wiped when I reset the device). Is it possible to have configurator do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you deployed a Configuration profile that mandates a password requirement, you will need to remove that profile via your MDM or Apple Configurator.

In the Profiles section of either Prepare or Supervise, ensure that none of the configuration profiles that are being deployed contain a payload requiring a passcode.

Comment: Do you mean in the Passcode section of the Prepare i should have no payload configured for any profile for the device? I'm a little unclear.

Comment: Added some detail to the answer; see if that help clear things up.

Comment: Can you tell me where in the profiles the requirement is hiding? I removed the **Passcode Payload Settings** from all profiles, but it's still requiring a passcode be set up on refresh.